# civievent - add 2097 participiant to an event

Tags: civievent, contacts, search

I tried to add 2097 contacts as a participant to an event. 
procedure:
 - search 
 - advanced search for "individuals" 
 - action add 2097 participants to an event 
 - waited for more than one hour 
 - it didn't add the participants to this event, no error message

I did the same procedure with 1597 contacts and it works. is there a limit?

Answer (score 4):

It's likely a configuration limit on your server that doesn't handle "big" operations

There is an upper limit on how much "stuff" you can do, and your webserver has a limit on how long a page can work (usually 30 sec) and how much memory it can use.

It might be that you hit one of these limits. If you have access to the log on the server, check if there is an error written when you try to do that operation... hard to be more detailed, it depends on your server and how it's configured.